# WGAN-GP Large Oscillating Loss

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to train a WaveGAN as described here: https://github.com/chrisdonahue/wavegan

In the paper, the WaveGAN is trained using WGAN-GP, so I have tried to implement it myself by adapting code from: https://github.com/LynnHo/DCGAN-LSGAN-WGAN-GP-DRAGAN-Tensorflow-2. However, after even only 2000 steps (~1 epoch), the loss values I am getting for the critic and the generator are large (< 1000) and oscillate between negative and positive. My audio is the same piano recordings that they used, just resampled at 16000Hz and converted to mono from stereo.

My loss graphs are:

[image]

I was hoping someone could please validate whether my implementation is correct and if so, what experiments can I run to diagnose this problem?

Note: `TIMESTEPS` indicates the number of samples I wish to generate for each generator pass. Currently this is set to 1 to replicate WaveGAN, and I wish to experiment with this in the future. For now, I don't think it is relevant to the issue.

My `train.py` script is:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
import librosa
import random
import os
import sys
import time

import GANModels

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)

MODEL_DIMS = 64
NUM_SAMPLES = 16384
TIMESTEPS = 1
D_UPDATES_PER_G_UPDATE = 5
GRADIENT_PENALTY_WEIGHT = 10.0
NOISE_LEN = 100
EPOCHS = 2000
EPOCHS_PER_SAMPLE = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 8
Fs = 16000

class GAN:
    def __init__(self, model_dims=MODEL_DIMS, num_samples=NUM_SAMPLES, timesteps=TIMESTEPS, gradient_penalty_weight=GRADIENT_PENALTY_WEIGHT,
                 noise_len=NOISE_LEN, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, sr=Fs):
        self.model_dims = model_dims
        self.num_samples = num_samples
        self.timesteps = timesteps
        self.noise_dims = (timesteps, noise_len)
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        self.G = GANModels.Generator(self.model_dims, self.timesteps, num_samples)
        self.D = GANModels.Critic(self.model_dims, self.timesteps, num_samples)

        self.G_optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=1e-4, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.9)
        self.D_optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=1e-4, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.9)

        print(self.G.summary())
        print(self.D.summary())

        self.gradient_penalty_weight = gradient_penalty_weight

        self.sr = sr

    def _d_loss_fn(self, r_logit, f_logit):
        r_loss = - tf.reduce_mean(r_logit)
        f_loss = tf.reduce_mean(f_logit)
        return r_loss, f_loss

    def _g_loss_fn(self, f_logit):
        f_loss = - tf.reduce_mean(f_logit)
        return f_loss

    def _gradient_penalty(self, real, fake):
        def _interpolate(a, b):
            shape = [tf.shape(a)[0]] + [1] * (a.shape.ndims - 1)
            alpha = tf.random.uniform(shape=shape, minval=0., maxval=1.)
            inter = a + alpha * (b - a)
            inter.set_shape(a.shape)
            return inter

        x = _interpolate(real, fake)
        with tf.GradientTape() as t:
            t.watch(x)
            pred = self.D(x, training=True)

        grad = t.gradient(pred, x)
        norm = tf.norm(tf.reshape(grad, [tf.shape(grad)[0], -1]), axis=1)
        gp = tf.reduce_mean((norm - 1.)**2)

        return gp

    @tf.function
    def train_G(self):
        with tf.GradientTape() as t:
            z = tf.random.normal(shape=(self.batch_size,) + self.noise_dims)
            x_fake = self.G(z, training=True)
            x_fake_d_logit = self.D(x_fake, training=True)
            G_loss = self._g_loss_fn(x_fake_d_logit)

        G_grad = t.gradient(G_loss, self.G.trainable_variables)
        self.G_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(G_grad, self.G.trainable_variables))

        return {'g_loss': G_loss}

    @tf.function
    def train_D(self, x_real):
        with tf.GradientTape() as t:
            z = tf.random.normal(shape=(x_real.shape[0],) + self.noise_dims) #Half fake and half real
            x_fake = self.G(z, training=True)

            x_real_d_logit = self.D(x_real, training=True)
            x_fake_d_logit = self.D(x_fake, training=True)

            x_real_d_loss, x_fake_d_loss = self._d_loss_fn(x_real_d_logit, x_fake_d_logit)
            gp = self._gradient_penalty(x_real, x_fake)

            D_loss = (x_real_d_loss + x_fake_d_loss) + gp * self.gradient_penalty_weight

        D_grad = t.gradient(D_loss, self.D.trainable_variables)
        self.D_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(D_grad, self.D.trainable_variables))

        return {'d_loss': x_real_d_loss + x_fake_d_loss, 'gp': gp}

    def sample(self, epoch, num_samples=10):
        z = tf.random.normal(shape=(num_samples,) + self.noise_dims)
        result = self.G(z, training=False)
        for i in range(num_samples):
            audio = np.array(result[i, :, :])
            audio.flatten()
            librosa.output.write_wav(f"output/piano/{epoch}-{i}.wav", audio, sr=self.sr)


#############################################################################

gan = GAN()

X_train = []
for file in os.listdir(r"D:\ML_Datasets\mancini_piano\piano\train"):
    with open(r"D:\ML_Datasets\mancini_piano\piano\train" + fr"\{file}", "rb") as f:
        samples, _ = librosa.load(f, Fs)
        if len(samples) < TIMESTEPS*NUM_SAMPLES:
            audio = np.array([np.array([sample]) for sample in samples])
            padding = np.zeros(shape=(TIMESTEPS*NUM_SAMPLES - len(samples), 1), dtype='float32')
            X_train.append(np.append(audio, padding, axis=0))
        else:
            for i in range(len(samples) // (TIMESTEPS*NUM_SAMPLES)):
                X_train.append(np.array([np.array([sample]) for sample in samples[:TIMESTEPS*NUM_SAMPLES]]))
                samples = np.delete(samples, np.s_[:TIMESTEPS*NUM_SAMPLES])

print(f"X_train shape = {(len(X_train),) + X_train[0].shape}")

librosa.output.write_wav("output/piano/test.wav", X_train[0], sr=Fs)

train_summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer("logs/train")

with train_summary_writer.as_default():
    steps_per_epoch = len(X_train) // BATCH_SIZE

    for e in range(EPOCHS):
        for i in range(steps_per_epoch):
            D_loss_sum = 0

            for n in range(D_UPDATES_PER_G_UPDATE):
                D_loss_dict = gan.train_D(np.array(random.sample(X_train, BATCH_SIZE)))
                D_loss_sum += D_loss_dict['d_loss']

            D_loss = D_loss_sum / D_UPDATES_PER_G_UPDATE

            G_loss_dict = gan.train_G()
            G_loss = G_loss_dict['g_loss']

            tf.summary.scalar('d_loss', D_loss, step=(e*steps_per_epoch)+i)
            tf.summary.scalar('g_loss', G_loss, step=(e*steps_per_epoch)+i)

            print(f"step {(e*steps_per_epoch)+i}: d_loss = {D_loss} g_loss = {G_loss}")

        if e % EPOCHS_PER_SAMPLE == 0:
            gan.sample(e)
```

My `GANModels.py` script is:

```py
def Generator(d, a, num_samples, c=16):

    # Prelim layers
    input_layer = Input(shape=(100,))

    dense_layer0 = Dense(256*d, input_shape=(100,))(input_layer)#
    reshape_layer0 = Reshape((c, c*d))(dense_layer0)#
    relu_layer0 = Activation('relu')(reshape_layer0)#

    # WaveCNN layers
    c //= 2
    expanded_layer0 = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, axis=1))(relu_layer0)#relu_layer1
    conv1d_t_layer0 = Conv2DTranspose(c*d, (1, 25), strides=(1, 4), padding='same')(expanded_layer0)
    slice_layer0 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0])(conv1d_t_layer0)
    relu_layer2 = Activation('relu')(slice_layer0)

    c //= 2
    expanded_layer1 = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, axis=1))(relu_layer2)
    conv1d_t_layer1 = Conv2DTranspose(c*d, (1, 25), strides=(1, 4), padding='same')(expanded_layer1)
    slice_layer1 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0])(conv1d_t_layer1)
    relu_layer3 = Activation('relu')(slice_layer1)

    c //= 2
    expanded_layer2 = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, axis=1))(relu_layer3)
    conv1d_t_layer2 = Conv2DTranspose(c*d, (1, 25), strides=(1, 4), padding='same')(expanded_layer2)
    slice_layer2 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0])(conv1d_t_layer2)
    relu_layer4 = Activation('relu')(slice_layer2)

    c //= 2
    expanded_layer3 = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, axis=1))(relu_layer4)
    conv1d_t_layer3 = Conv2DTranspose(c*d, (1, 25), strides=(1, 4), padding='same')(expanded_layer3)
    slice_layer3 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0])(conv1d_t_layer3)
    relu_layer5 = Activation('relu')(slice_layer3)

    expanded_layer4 = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, axis=1))(relu_layer5)
    conv1d_t_layer4 = Conv2DTranspose(1, (1, 25), strides=(1, 4), padding='same')(expanded_layer4)#strides=(1,1)
    slice_layer4 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0])(conv1d_t_layer4)
    tanh_layer0 = Activation('tanh')(slice_layer4)

    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=tanh_layer0)

    return model

def _apply_phaseshuffle(x, rad=2, pad_type='reflect'):
    b, x_len, nch = x.get_shape().as_list()

    phase = tf.random.uniform([], minval=-rad, maxval=rad + 1, dtype=tf.int32)
    pad_l = tf.maximum(phase, 0)
    pad_r = tf.maximum(-phase, 0)
    phase_start = pad_r
    x = tf.pad(x, [[0, 0], [pad_l, pad_r], [0, 0]], mode=pad_type)

    x = x[:, phase_start:phase_start+x_len]
    x.set_shape([b, x_len, nch])

    return x

def Critic(d, a, num_samples, c=1):

    input_layer = Input(shape=(a*num_samples, 1))#d*d

    conv1d_layer0 = Conv1D(c*d, 25, strides=4, padding='same')(input_layer)#//2
    LReLU_layer0 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(conv1d_layer0)
    phaseshuffle_layer0 = Lambda(lambda x: _apply_phaseshuffle(x))(LReLU_layer0)

    c *= 2
    conv1d_layer1 = Conv1D(c*d, 25, strides=4, padding='same')(phaseshuffle_layer0)#d
    LReLU_layer1 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(conv1d_layer1)
    phaseshuffle_layer1 = Lambda(lambda x: _apply_phaseshuffle(x))(LReLU_layer1)

    c *= 2
    conv1d_layer2 = Conv1D(c*d, 25, strides=4, padding='same')(phaseshuffle_layer1)#2*d
    LReLU_layer2 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(conv1d_layer2)
    phaseshuffle_layer2 = Lambda(lambda x: _apply_phaseshuffle(x))(LReLU_layer2)

    c *= 2
    conv1d_layer3 = Conv1D(c*d, 25, strides=4, padding='same')(phaseshuffle_layer2)#4*d
    LReLU_layer3 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(conv1d_layer3)
    phaseshuffle_layer3 = Lambda(lambda x: _apply_phaseshuffle(x))(LReLU_layer3)

    c *= 2
    conv1d_layer4 = Conv1D(c*d, 25, strides=4, padding='same')(phaseshuffle_layer3)#8*d,strides=4
    LReLU_layer4 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(conv1d_layer4)
    phaseshuffle_layer4 = Lambda(lambda x: _apply_phaseshuffle(x))(LReLU_layer4)

    slice_layer0 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0])(phaseshuffle_layer4)

    dense_layer1 = Dense(1, input_shape=(256*d,))(slice_layer0)

    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=dense_layer1)

    return model
```

Comment: I have a similar issue. Were you able to resolve your question?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone finding this via search, I would like to share how I solved a similar issue I encountered for a Wasserstein GAN with gradient penalty. In my case, I also observed a loss oscillation similar to the one mentioned in the question.
Tuning hyperparameters did not bring any improvement.

Finally, I found the **Lipschitz Penalty** as a replacement for the gradient penalty. In my case, this completely resolved the oscillation issue and the model started to train without any issues. With the change the discriminator loss decreased continiously:

[Observed Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bBMF.png)

The corresponding paper is [here](https://openreview.net/forum?id=B1hYRMbCW) and the authors published their tensorflow source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/lukovnikov/improved_wgan_training) (Interesting lines are, for example, lines 155-158 in gan_mnist.py). Basically, the idea is to clamp the gradient penalty to 0 as the lower limit. Original code:

```
if not ONE_SIDED:
    # This is the standard gradient penalty
    gradient_penalty = tf.reduce_mean((slopes-1.)**2)
else:
    # Standard gradient pental
    gradient_penalty = tf.reduce_mean(tf.clip_by_value(slopes - 1., 0., np.infty)**2)
```

In PyTorch, the equivalent step of the gradient computation would look like this (everything else is just standard gradient penalty computation):

```
if not lipschitz_penalty:
    # WGAN-GP Gradient Penalty for comparison
    penalty = ((slopes - 1) ** 2).mean()
else:
    # Lipschitz Penalty
    penalty = (torch.clamp(slopes - 1., min=0, max=None) ** 2).mean()
```

I hope this will help future visitors.

Comment: this is very helpful and indeed solve the problem! thank you!